# Cant find libboost_system.so.1.43.0 in eclipse using boost

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I am trying to run boost in eclipse,

under Library search path I have put:
/home/etobkru/boost_1_43_0/boostBinaries/lib/
and under Libraries I have put all the libs, boost_system, etc.

The build is working without errors but when am trying to run the program I get an error:

**error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.43.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

This file is under /home/etobkru/boost_1_43_0/boostBinaries/lib/ but I dont know how to make eclipse search in that directory.

Comment: Had the same problem today and posted my solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12588306/1627336

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say what OS you're running.  But as root, try:

```
echo '/home/etobkru/boost_1_43_0/boostBinaries/lib/' >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/etobkru_boost.conf
ldconfig -v
```

EDIT: If you don't have root, you can try:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/etobkru/boost_1_43_0/boostBinaries/lib/" my_command
```

[`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) is a colon-separated list of extra directories.