# Program compiles fine with boost libs, but error when running it

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, redhat

## In a nutshell...

C++ program (using the boost libraries) compiles fine in Eclipse, but then “error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory” it shown when running it.

---

## Details

I am running a basic program on C++ to check that I can use the boost threading libraries correctly.

```
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void hello ()
{
    Std::cout<<”Hello, I am a thread”<<std::endl;
}

int main ()
{
    boost::thread th1(&hello);
    th1.join();
}
```

The code compiles fine, so I believed that I had installed and set up the boost libraries correctly (added directories to include etc)

However when I try to run the program I get the following error message in the consol

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.46.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: did you try to find the libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 file on your system? Is it in the search path?

Comment: libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 is on my system, I can find it no problem. It's availble in the library directory too.

Comment: Is there anything you have to do to shared library (.so) files to make LD_LIBRARY_PATH see them?

Answer (score 6):

I had a very similar issue with FreeFileSYnc, compiles fine but won't launch due to a libboost thread error :

```
FreeFileSync: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.51.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

To fix it I did :

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib
```

It may help other people.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked if the `libboost_thread.so.1.46.1` is present at `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?
Copy the library at your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, this path is searched for dynamic libraries(so) at runtime.

Comment: Doing echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH gives a blank response

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is the set of paths the compiler looks into while searching for the static or shared libraries specified for linking. One generally specifies only the path and not the library in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. This error is during execution which is when the dynamic library is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

boost thread is a *dynamic* library. It must be found at runtime for the program to run (like a DLL in Windows).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but hassled all day with the same problem. I recently installed the latest `boost 1_51_0` locally into my `$HOME/bin/boost_1_51_0`. 
What worked for me, was to export the include and library path by adding these lines to my `.bash_rc`:

```
export CPP_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/bin/boost_1_51_0/include
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/bin/boost_1_51_0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then add the include path and lib path to your `Makefile`:

```
INCLUDE_BOOST += -I$(HOME)/bin/boost_1_51_0/include
LDLIBS_BOOST  += -L$(HOME)/bin/boost_1_51_0/lib

CPPFLAGS += $(INCLUDE)
CPPFLAGS += $(INCLUDE_BOOST)
```

Then you can add the libs from `1_51` via

```
LDLIBS += -lm
LDLIBS += -lboost_filesystem
LDLIBS += -lboost_chrono
LDLIBS += -lboost_timer
LDLIBS += -lboost_system

$(TARGET): $(SRCS)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDLIBS_BOOST) $(SRCS) $(LDLIBS)  $(OPT)  -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and `ldconfig` did not fix it.

If you, as I did, installed the boost libraries using a plain `bjam` command, chances are you installed the libraries in a *stage* subfolder. [See this page as a reference](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/introduction-installation). What worked for me was to run the following:

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/include/boost_1_64_0/stage/lib
```